# SOA question regarding transformation of variables.

Tags: probability

[image]

my working is this: 
[image]

for this x= 2t1 + t2. I chose Y=T2 so that t2=y and t1= (x-y)/2. now the joint distribution of t1,t2 is exp(-t1-t2). i plugged in the values of t1 and t2 in terms of x and y and then took the partial derivates for the jocobian to find the joint function of x,y and then integrated y out from 0 to infinity as that is the limit of t2=y but i can't seem to get the correct answer. however if i put the upper limit as x instead of infinity, i do get the correct answer. can anyone please explain why x is the upper limit in this case?

Comment: It looks like you are doing a change of variables $(T_1, T_2) \leftrightarrow (X,Y)$ with $Y=T_2, X=2T_1+T_2$.  In that case we have $X\geq Y$ always, how is that considered in your density functions?

Comment: With the correction I mention above, you can continue your method to get the correct answer.  However, I personally would do this problem by writing, for a given $x>0$:  $$P[2T_1 + T_2 > x] = \int_{0}^{\infty}P[2T_1+T_2>x|T_1=t]f_{T_1}(t)dt$$ and continuing on.

Comment: @Michael as y is simply equal to t2, shouldn't the bounds of t2 apply to y, i.e. t2>0. yes x is greater than y as it's adding another positive number, but i don't get how that makes x an upper limit in the integral.

Comment: i don't know how to do the method you posted sir.

Comment: For your way: Can you explain how you get a nonzero density for $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ in the region $y>x$?  (For my way:  Note that $P[2T_1 + T_2>x|T_1=t]$ can be computed easily.)  Both ways (when done correctly) give the same answer, which is indeed one of the choices (A)-(E) given above.

Comment: Essentially the same question: Can you explain why you (correctly) get a zero density for $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ in the region $x<0$?

Comment: Honestly no. I think you're overestimating my capabilities.

Comment: So then consider a simpler problem:  Let $Z$ be an exponential random variable with rate parameter $\lambda>0$.  Can you give the density $f_Z(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{R}$? Then show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Z(z)dz = 1$?

Comment: Doesn't z need to be greater or equal to 0 and not all of R? Then you can split the integral which will be 0 from -infinity to 0  and 1 from 0 to infinity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79818/discussion-between-syed-bukhari-and-michael).

Comment: I just saw this now, and I gave some further comments in the chat area.